# java pick up CEST/CET from string

Tags: java, date, timezone

I have strings like:
 
02/03/07 11:13:33 CEST or 
02/03/07 11:13:33 CET.

How do I parse it to a util.Date in such a way that it considers cet/cest?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SimpleDateFormat` object to do it:

`Date d=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss z").parse(string);`

Here `z` stands for the zone.

Comment: I'd use `HH` (24-hour clock) instead of `hh` (12-hour clock) for the hours.

Comment: oh ya thanks for the heads up. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SimpleDateFormat` with the right format string:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss z");

String text1 = "02/03/07 11:13:33 CEST";
String text2 = "02/03/07 11:13:33 CET";

Date d1 = df.parse(text1);
Date d2 = df.parse(text2);
```